# Rails Active Record - How to use build when there is an initialize method in associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model called "User" with has many association to "Address" model.

When I do User.new.addresses.build, I am getting following error,

```
    ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:162:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:162:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:162:in `build_association'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:423:in `build_record'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:102:in `build'
    from (irb):10
```

This happens when i add an initialize method in Address model.

Any help is highly appreciated...

EDITED:

There are no arguments to the initialize method and it looks like this

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :test

  def initialize
    test = "manu"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to override the initialize method of an ActiveRecord inherited class.
Use `after_initialize` callback if you want to add your custom initialization. See the rails api for all the [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Answer (score 2):

`after_initialize` hook should serve your purpose

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :test
  after_initialize :init

  def init
    @test = "manu"
  end
end
```